# static files are recieved but not working in django

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-2.7, django-1.7

I am working with django 1.7,

here is my settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
)

STATIC_ROOT = "absolute/path/to/static"
```

here assets is the folder i created and contains all css and js files. After that i run the command collectstatic and a static folder was created.

this is how i call the css and js file in my html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Login</title>

<link href="{% static '/static/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

the problem is when i run the server all the css and js files are received(showing 200 ok in the developer section) but the css is not applied, i mean the html page looks raw as if not css was applied.

What am i doing wrong, I am new to django can anyone point me to the right direction

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I am getting this in the browser developer console

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: ".../static/css/bootstrap.min.css".

Comment: to solve the problem, add `type="text/css"`.

Comment: @laike9m not working...

Answer (score 1):

You should strip `/static/` prefix from the path to css file:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```